# Rewriting URL in IIS7

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I want to create a URL rewrite rule in IIS.

When inputting "hr.company.org" in the browser i want it to go to "https://hub.company.org/sites/hr" which is sitecollection in a sharepoint site.
there is no site with name "hr.company.org"

Would such a redirect be possible. If it is please guide me on how to do this.

**EDIT**
 i have now added "hr.company.org" to the hosts file in sys32. and it now displays the root hub.company.org website.. how can i add rule to redirect to /sites/hr

Also changed to iis7

Comment: Not sure for IIS 6, but you can do a permanent Redirect in IIS 7 and up.

Comment: in IIS7 would it be possible to redirect from a site that does not exist.?

Comment: No, Both the sites need to exist, so when the user tries to access  the older one the redirect code is hit and redirects to  the other site.

Comment: i have now iis7.. and that website is now configured in hosts file in sys32/drivers...  Can you guide me on how i can add the redirect. google wasnt of enough help :(

Answer (score 0):

This should fix you situation.

1. Select your Website -> Choose Http Redirect
2. Enter the new addres(See second image)

[image: Website -> Http Redirect]
[image: Add the new address here (instead of (www.google.com)]